# Pass information to Java Web Start?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm new on java webstart. I'm launching it from my web browser using an embedded jnlp link in the page, it works fine. But I would like to know if there is any way to pass some information from my page to jnlp. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamicly generate a JNLP file for a Java Web Start application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986595/dynamicly-generate-a-jnlp-file-for-a-java-web-start-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to generate the jnlp dynamically, for instance using a servlet or a jsp file. You need to set the content type so the client can understand that it's a webstart application:

```
response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
```